# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "de buten"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, coloquialismos, españa

En el Diccionario de la Lengua figura la palabra [**buten**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6M392cQ) sin definición alguna, y a continuación la expresión

> de buten
>
> 1. loc. adj. jerg. Excelente, estupendo. U. t. c. loc. adv.

sin más datos.

Buscando en el CORDE, apenas aparecen 9 casos, siendo el más antiguo de 1888, mientras que en el NTLLE he visto que aparece por primera vez en el diccionario de Zerolo (1895).

¿De dónde viene la expresión?

Por cierto, es la primera vez que veo (o al menos, que me doy cuenta) una  palabra sin definición en el DLE

Comment: Pero a ver, entonces, cada vez que yo he dicho "dabuten" o incluso "dabuti", ¿en realidad tenía que decir "de buten"? No lo sabía, ¡muy buena! Y lo de las palabras sin definiciones es cierto que a veces pasa, yo me topé con una precisamente con la pregunta de "voto a bríos".

Comment: Para mi siempre ha sido "dabuten", también he oído "dabuti" o "debuti" pero creo que nunca "de buten". La teoría que conozco, no sé si es cierta, es que viene del alemán *guten* pero ni idea de como llegó al habla popular en España.

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente, parece que la palabra *buten* por sí sola no significa nada, y hay pocos casos en el CORDE, siendo los primeros de finales del siglo XIX, como comentas. Para estos casos en cuando conviene comenzar a investigar en el fichero general, y ver qué comentan las cédulas allí presentes sobre la palabra *buten*.

La primera que me encuentro con datos interesantes comenta lo ya adelantado por @blonfu:

> Según Belmonte, del alemán *guten*; según J.M. Medina, de *butyrum*. Se usa también en la Argentina.

Otra ficha parece identificar el término como un gitanismo. Otra como procedente de la germanía. Otra incide en su origen del alemán *guten* y explica que la expresión completa era *de buten niquelá*. Esto me resulta curioso, porque en Andalucía usamos la expresión "estar niquelado" o "niquelao" para decir que algo está perfecto ("-¿Qué tal el examen? -Niquelao."). Otra comenta que al principio se usaba casi exclusivamente para referirse a mujeres.

Encuentro otra ficha que hace referencia al *Vobaculario andaluz*, que explica lo mismo que la mencionada arriba sobre los dos posibles orígenes, pero añade que *butyrum* significa *leche y miel*, y que su significado es *abundante*, como en "fue una comida de buten".

Si juntamos todo lo anterior, el resultado (y esto ya es divagación mía) es que *buten* podría ser una palabra de origen andaluz, pero originada por gitanos que viajaran por Europa e incorporaran palabras extranjeras a su habla, como podría ser *guten* del alemán.

En todo caso, queda claro que es una palabra que se usa siempre (y en esto coinciden todas las fichas consultadas) precedida de la preposición *de*, consistiendo pues ambas en una locución inseparable cuyas palabras sueltas carecen de significado.

Comment: En el NTLLE veo que dan como origen *Germ* (diccionarios más antiguos) o *Caló* en los más modernos, no citando ninguno ni el alemán"gut" o "guten", ni el *butyrum* [que creo que es mantequilla en latin]. Curiosamente, el diccionario de Alemany y Bolufer (1917) menciona que procede "**de cierta imprecación contra Dios, frecuente en boca de los ingleses**".

Comment: @user17232 la abreviatura "germ" es la de "germanía", y el caló es la lengua de los gitanos. Ambos orígenes (germanía y gitanos) están comentados en las fichas. Yo solo estoy transmitiendo los datos que he encontrado, aunque la verdad es que el origen no queda claro. Podría ser interesante saber cuál era esa "imprecación contra Dios".

Comment: Supongo que la imprecación sería *goddamn*. No acabo de ver la traslación semántica, en cualquier caso.

Answer (score 2):

En otros lugares me reí mucho al ver las procedencias y versiones de algunos términos en sus inventivas populares, observe que también había foros como el actual que se hacían eco de la misma cuestión y que suscitaba, la voz "Dabuten", cierto interes.

Así que repetiré lo mismo, al menos para dejar cierta constancia sobre su procedencia y la deformación etimológica que ha sufrido, pues existe gran confusión al respecto que puedo ayudar a esclarecer.

En la nueva voz "Dabuten", que me toco vivir de cerca y que no tiene nada que ver con lo que he oído o leído de forma expresa, pues la original es "Daguten" y "Dagüten" en su versión original escrita y no "Dabuten".

Igualmente he visto que en otros textos, "Dabuten" se trata de relacionar con la palabra "bute" y la preposición "de", "Debuten" y a su vez mágicamente sin explicación alguna transformado en "da", "dabuten", con el significado de mucho, algo que vale mucho ó de calidad y que se utiliza hoy en día por los jóvenes, aspecto que también me hizo gracia, para indicar algo que es genial.

Realmente conocí la palabra a últimos del verano del año 1978, no como Dabuten sino como Daguten, y entre nosotros al referirnos a ella de forma escrita lo transcribíamos como Dagüten.

A principios de ese verano algunos amigos y compañeros que estudiaban en el instituto estuvieron en Alemania. Al regresar de su estancia allí, recuerdo que no paraban de formular esta locución, Dagüten", para casi todo, como algo estupendo, genial, excelente, al igual que hacíamos con la palabra "guay", anterior a ella con unos meses de diferencia. Sin embargo, todo el grupo de amigos adoptamos rápidamente la nueva expresión sin cuestionarnos ninguna pregunta sobre su procedencia u otras "insignificancias" en aquel momento, ya que nos pareció graciosa, innovadora y expresaba para lo mismo  que la palabra "guay" pero en aquella época "dagüten" sonaba más informal para ciertas actitudes que es lo que se pretendía y era más "dagüten". Con el paso del tiempo, pregunte a uno de esos amigos que habían estado en Alemania el por que empleaban tanto esa palabra, a lo que me respondió, que se habían reído mucho con ella estando en Alemana, pues la oyeron para mencionar a la cerveza de calidad ó como expresión de buena cerveza "Das Güten bier", algo que por el sonido al escuchar en el momento les pareció gracioso en Español, desde entonces cada vez que tomaban una cerveza para referirse aquello decían Daguten, y los otros del grupo respondían daguten, daguten y todos se reían en una inofensiva muestra de alegría, como indicando de que la cerveza era de calidad ó estaba buena y rica de sabor.
Cuando regresaron de Alemania, todo había estado Dagüten y aquello que les parecía estupendo, guay ó chachi era Daguten que no Dabuten y que nosotros escribiamos "Dagüten" simplemente para remarcar su componente exótico y llamativo, ya que nuestros amigos habían estado en Alemania, que en aquella época no dejaba de ser una aventura.

Leyendo cosas en internet, sobre la procedencia de algunas voces, me hizo mucha gracia al ver en que se ha convertido aquello que viví y me impulso a escribir sobre ello en una especie de recuerdo lejano que con el tiempo ha ido transformando la palabra, cambiando vocales, incluso alguna consonante como "g", vario a "b", como cuando en plan gracioso dices de "bueno", "güeno" y "wueno". En este caso la evolución ha ido a la inversa y se ha ido extendiendo a otras formas cambiantes como dabuten, dabut, debute’, ‘debuti’, ‘debuten.

Realmente en Alemán "Das guten, por si mismo significa el bueno, lo bueno, el bien, Das Güten, la bondad, gut, bien, gute, calidad.

Esta ha sido la historia de "Dagüten", vivida por esas casualidades de la vida entre otras, que ha evolucionado hasta "Dabute", aunque en mi caso siempre me referiré a ella como Daguten.

Diego

Comment: Si, lo he visto y la voz aparece en Miau como "de abuten". Aunque yo lo conociera en aquella época vinculada a una relación con la cerveza "Das Güten bier", eso no invalida que la voz ya existente, proceda del alemán Da guten, pues en esta lengua Das guten, por si mismo significa el bueno, lo bueno, el bien, Das Güten, la bondad, gut, bien, gute, calidad... lo mismo que expresa "Debuten". Aunque seguiré investigando. De todas formas gracias.

Comment: Conversación con Óscar García... Respecto a su etimología, uno de sus posibles orígenes en el idioma alemán, ‘Das Guten’, ‘Esto es bueno’. Otro posible origen viene de la lengua ‘caló’ y de juntar las palabras ‘de’ y ‘buten’. Lo cierto es que Benito Pérez Galdós ya la usó en 1888 en su novela ‘Miau’ en la forma ‘de abuten’ y también se puede escuchar en un diálogo de la adaptación al cine de La verbena de la Paloma (1894). Supongo que es una palabra que tuvo su auge en los últimos años setenta y primeros ochenta, en los barrios del sur de Madrid...

Answer (score 1):

Pues yo recuerdo una novela que leí hace muchos años (imposible recordar título ni autor) en la que se narraba la vida de un "quinqui" madrileño en segunda persona (un narrador omnisciente contaba la historia con "tú pensabas"; "cuando fuiste al bar"; "el comisario te dijo"...) y la expresión "de buten" se relacionaba con un gitanismo según el cual "bute" o "buten" en caló se refiere a una tela de excelente calidad. Puede venir del germanismo guten y los viajes de los nómadas gitanos o no, sería perfectamente compatible... Así, algo de buten es algo muy bueno, excepcional.

El cheli madrileño era mezcla de casticismo y marginalidad y tomaba muchas expresiones del caló así que fácilmente "de buten" pudo degenerar en dabuten o debuti...

Comment: Leo en [Diccionario gitano/Vocabulario caló](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Diccionario_gitano/Vocabulario_caló-castellano#B) que _but_ quiere decir "muy", _bute_ "mucho" y _buter_ "más, además". Parece fácil que de "muy", "mucho" se derive "muy bueno". También, una palabra para excelente, excepcional, puede ser _baré_, _baró_ o _barí_.