# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "corrupia"?

Tags: etimología

El diccionario de la lengua, en la entrada  [**corrupia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B0eNmIk) simplemente remite a **fiera corrupia**. En [**fiera corrupia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HsDQ07D) se define como

> 1. f. U. para designar ciertas figuras animales que se presentan en fiestas populares y son famosas por su deformidad o aspecto espantable.

En el NTLLE solo se recoge **corrupia** en los diccionarios de la RAE de los años 1983, 1984, 1989 y 1992, y del mismo modo: no se define **corrupia** y remite a **fiera corrupia**. En la edición de 1984 se añade una segunda acepción: "Persona cruel o de muy mal carácter", que no aparece en las demás ediciones.

El CORDE solo recoge 8 casos de **fiera corrupia** en 5 documentos, entre 1926 y 1970.

Otra fuente, [**yorokubu.es**](http://www.yorokobu.es/la-fiera-corrupia/), recoge:

> Una Fiera Corrupia es un tipo de animal mitológico de aspecto horrible, deforme y amenazador. Hoy nos daría risa, mucho más estando tan acostumbrados a la visión de bichejos tipo Alien. Pero entre los siglos XVIII y XIX pensar e imaginar una de estas bestias debía dar terror.
>
> Se popularizaron gracias a los romances de ciego y la literatura de cordel, esos pliegos atados por un cordel o una caña que se vendían al público contando fábulas, leyendas o acontecimientos de la época narrados por los ciegos que iban de un pueblo a otro ganándose la vida como juglares.

mientras que el [**Centro Virtual Cervantes**](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/mayo_04/19052004_01.htm) da diversas descripciones de su aspecto, basadas en textos de Pio Baroja y Jose Maria Iribarren.

He encntrado incluso una obra de teatro reciente con ese título: [**La fiera corrupia**](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra/la-fiera-corrupia--0/).

Queda claro qué es una **fiera corrupia**, pero ¿de dónde viene la propia palabra **corrupia**? Porque no he encontrado una sola referencia a la etimología de la palabreja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el mismo procedimiento que con [mi respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22876/12637) a tu pregunta sobre *de buten*, veamos qué dicen las fichas sobre "corrupia" (y son pocas):

> Vocabulario de León. Corrupia. En La Bañeza y su comarca, calleja o calle estrecha.

Posiblemente una acepción muy regional que no tenga nada que ver con el tema que nos trata. Sigamos. Un libro sobre el bable dice:

> *La peste, la fiera corrupia*: epidemia, mal genérico que no existe. *Yes igual que la peste corrupia. Póneste con unu que paezes una fiera corrupia.*

Resulta interesante saber que no solo se aplica a *fiera*, sino también a *peste*. La siguiente ficha es interesante:

> Corrupia. Ser monstruoso.

Los ejemplos de esta ficha hablan de "fiera corrupia" como el nombre de un ser monstruoso, pero también parece dar un significado a la palabra "corrupia" por sí sola. Buscando por Ngram he encontrado el siguiente texto:

> *... las relaciones de casos monstruosos é increíbles y de seres extraordinarios ó fabulosos como La arpía americana (hoy La Corrupia).*
>
> Francisco Navarro y Ledesma, "Lecciones de literatura explicadas en el Instituto de San Isidro, de Madrid", 1902 (España).

Así que es posible que "Corrupia" fuera el nombre de un ser mitológico monstruoso. No he encontrado nada más en ninguna otra ficha, aunque una recoge la palabra como "corrupio/a", pero en el CORDE no he encontrado ningún caso de "corrupio". Y una última ficha digna de mención hace referencia al libro *El porqué de los dichos*, de José María Iribarren. En este se recoge la expresión, pero así:

> La fiera Corrupia.

Lo que indica, como en otras fichas hemos visto, que "Corrupia" es sencillamente un nombre propio.

> La Corrupia [...] tenía cabeza de toro (con cuernos gachos, descomunales) y cuerpo de lagarto, lleno de escamas. Sus uñas eran como ganchos de romana (de balanza romana), y para su exterminio fue necesaria la intervención de todo un regimiento de infantería de línea.

En [esta página](http://www.yorokobu.es/la-fiera-corrupia/) tratan el tema, y aclaran que según quién contara la leyenda la bestia tenía otros nombres, como la "Fiera Zurrupia" o "Currupia", y otros. Y añade:

> La cuestión es que, según Pío Baroja en su obra Vitrina pintoresca (1935), la Fiera Corrupia está inspirada en la Bestia del Apocalipsis y con el tiempo fue perdiendo su origen bíblico.

Comment: En resumen, que parece que es sencillamente un nombre propio?

Comment: @user17232 pues sí, eso parece. Échale un vistazo a la página de Yorokobu enlazada para más información.

Comment: Curiosamente la página de yorokobu la tengo puesta en la pregunta, pero no vi más que los primeros párrafos. Una duda: si es un nombre propio, ¿no lo pondria el DLE en mayúsculas como en el caso de otros nombres propios? Por ejemplo: Alzheimer http://dle.rae.es/?id=2B2GW59

Comment: @user17232 date cuenta de que la RAE es notaria, no juez. Solo da fe de lo que la gente usa para dar forma al idioma. En los textos del CORDE se ve que la gente usaba "fiera corrupia", pero no "Corrupia", luego se registró como adjetivo en vez de como nombre propio al usarlo la gente en minúscula.

Comment: Te ha referenciado lirondos :) https://twitter.com/lirondos/status/1274837746826334209

Answer (score 0):

Viene del Euskera.
Corrupia  < *Korr *Oro *Beha

> korr-oo-bia > korropia / corrupia.
>   Significado original:
>   Kor: propenso, tendente
>   Oro: todo, completo
>   Beha: mirar, observar
>   Kor oro beha: 
>   Tendencia a Observarlo Todo.
>   O bien al revés (dudoso):
>   Propenso a que todos le/la/lo observen.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido, Fernando! Es sin duda una etimología muy interesante. Veo que pones el texto como una cita, ¿podrías indicar cuál ha sido la fuente que has usado? Así la respuesta quedará más profesional y creíble, puesto que podremos contrastar la fuente. Para más información, consulta la sección [answer].