# ¿Cuándo se usa "estar dabuti", "estar dabuten" o "estar de buten"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, coloquialismos, españa

Entiendo que esta frase tiene 3 variantes:

- Estar dabuti
- Estar dabuten
- Estar de buten

... y que se utiliza mucho para significar que algo es genial y fantástico.

¿Se puede utilizarla para decir que alguien es genial? Y si lo es, ¿qué tipo de variante?

También, ¿se puede decir lo siguiente si estás muy bien?

- Estoy dabuti
- Estoy dabuten

Comment: Consulta esta otra pregunta, muy relacionada https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22864/de-d%C3%B3nde-viene-la-expresi%C3%B3n-de-buten

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Dabuten" y "dabuti" hace décadas que no se usan casi. Pertenecen a la jerga popular, y la jerga popular tiende a cambiar muy rápido. Son intercambiables, sin ninguna diferencia de significado entre ellas.

Sí, pueden (o podían) usarse para decir que alguien es genial:

> Este es un tío dabuti.

Y también pueden (o podían) usarse para indicar que uno mismo está muy bien:

> Desde que dejé el curro viejo estoy dabuten.

En general, en cualquier situación en la que se pueda decir "muy bien" se puede (o podía) decir "dabuten/dabuti". Pero me siento viejo tras escribir esos ejemplos.

Todo esto, referido al español de España. Los hablantes de otras variedades de español no creo que entiendan estas palabras.

Comment: Muchas gracias,  me interesa el desarrollo de la lengua, y sí, claro entiendo que es una frase madrileña.